# How to provide an inherited view controller that support a UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, protocols

I want to provide an helper view controller that complies to the UITableViewDataSource protocol. But this class is not intended to be, must be used finalized by inheritance.

Trying to do so, the compiler requires me to implement the protocol in the helper class.
How could I fix this?

```
class BigHeadViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Helper class that do ton of the job
}

class StoryTableViewController: BigHeadViewController {
    // final implementation, must implement UITableViewDataSource
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you can have an implementation of the UITableViewDataSource methods in your superclass with something along the lines of:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    precondition(false, "UITableViewDataSource method MUST be implemented in subclass of BigHeadViewController")    

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    precondition(false, "UITableViewDataSource method MUST be implemented in subclass of BigHeadViewController") 

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    precondition(false, "UITableViewDataSource method MUST be implemented in subclass of BigHeadViewController") 

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

When you implement the UITableViewDataSource methods in your subclass do not call super. This will ensure that required methods are implemented in subclasses, or provide you with an error message in the console when they are not (since the super method will be called when no subclass method is available).

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I would have a `UITableViewManager`, this would conform to `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` I would then subclass that for each tableview that requires a different type of data / cells.

I would have a pointer to the `UITableViewManager` on `BigHeadViewController` but would actually assign it with a subclass of `UITableViewManager` such as `MessageTableViewManager: UITableViewManager`

Then when you subclass `BigHeadViewController` you can override the var that is `UITableViewManager` and make a different sublcass of if to produce different data.